# Ajax binding with telerik - what is this meant to return?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Looking at: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/Grid?theme=vista

Can anyone tell me what _FirstLook() is meant to return?

It is implementing the paging I think.

```
        [GridAction]
        public ActionResult _FirstLook()
        {
            return View(new GridModel(GetOrderDto()));
        }
```

Every example I find calls a method `GetOrders()` or `GetOrderDto()` etc

Here is an example of that:

```
private IEnumerable<Order> GetOrders()
        {
            DataLoadOptions loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();

            loadOptions.LoadWith<Order>(o => o.Customer);
            northwind.LoadOptions = loadOptions;

            return northwind.Orders;
        }
```

Am I just meant to provide a subset of the list based upon the page number clicked? How is the value transferred?

It appears all of this is using a design pattern that I am not which is why its not making sense.

I am using ADO.NET Entity Data Model not LINQ-SQL like I think this is using, so I don't have `.LoadOptions` available. But surely I'm able to get this working using ADO.NET Entity Data Model rather than LINQ-SQL - it shouldn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short the `GridAction` attribute converts the `GridModel` object to JSON which then the grid is using to bind. The `GridModel` accepts an `IQueryable` returned from your data provider (our demos use Linq to SQL but you can easily use Entity Framework). The `GridAction` attribute will do the paging, sorting etc for you - you just need to pass an `IQueryable` in the `GridModel` constructor.

More details can be found in the [Grid Ajax Binding help topic](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-data-binding-ajax-binding.html).